# Magento 1.9 Missing Payment Options in Front End

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of weeks now and still haven't have any luck of solving my problem.

My issue is whenever i tried to checkout any product. **There is no payment options available**. Everything is set and enable in the admin panel including the permission of countries. I'm really wondering why the payment method / options doesn't shows up.

[Here's the screenshot of my front end displaying no payment options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qBx0.png)

[Here's my admin panel displaying that the Cash on Delivery payment method is enabled and allowed in different countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1pha.png)

sorry, I'm still new in magento development. Thank you :)